# Free C++ library for windows gui

Tags: c++, user-interface

I just want to write a very simple C++ program for Windows only that uses a GUI. What library for C++ is free and allows me to do this? (This code is not, and will never be, open source).

Comment: What is so tiny and simple, but cannot be open-sourced?

Comment: Laziness; I hate jumping through hoops.

Comment: The Windows API are free. No need to put another windowing library between you and windows API if it is a windows only.

Comment: Laziness seems to be pretty easy to open source. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

+1 for Qt.

Qt is bloody awesome. Once you've hacked around with QT you will never, ever want to go back to any other UI API. Seriously. It's. That. Good.

There's also a free IDE that you can use that makes development even more painless. Oh, and the community is very helpful and generally kicks ass.

[All Hail Qt!](http://qt.nokia.com)

Comment: Also, the documentation for Qt is very good

Comment: Profiling it can be less than pleasant though, heads up.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [WxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/).  From the blurb:

> Unlike other cross-platform toolkits,
>   wxWidgets gives its applications a
>   truly native look and feel because it
>   uses the platform's native API rather
>   than emulating the GUI. It's also
>   extensive, free, open-source and
>   mature.

Comment: But it's poorly, inconsistently, and sometimes erroneously documented...among other problems.

Comment: @Noah: Hey, that's what the source code is for! :)

Comment: @genpfault - except that it's an incomprehensible mess of macros a good portion of the time.

Comment: Qt uses native look too. I have used both Qt and WxWidgets, and I find Qt much better.

Comment: Qt uses it's own drawing engine, while wxWidgets relies on calling directly to the system's API. I know Roku wrote this years ago, but for what it's worth, wxWidgets has improved a lot, overall.

Answer (score 2):

GTK+ and for C++ GTKmm I guess.
Maybe but maybe also Qt.

Comment: I'd go for GTKmm unless you need automated testing, at which point it's utterly insufficient (doesn't implement ANY accessibility on win32).  The signal mechanism is a lot more expressive, generic, and powerful than Qt's, which require everything to be a Q_OBJECT and then they can't be templates or generated with the preprocessor.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could do that with [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com).

Answer (score 1):

[Here you go](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc534994.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

[WTL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163305.aspx) is quite popular. If you visit the SourceForge page you will see praise heaped upon the project.

Answer (score 1):

There are long fights about choosing free and/or portable GUI for c/c++ applications. Each programmer has his own favourite, and only few programmers have tried multiple of them so they can compare. So I suggest you to google some more for various comparations.

From what I hear all the free ones suffer lack of documentation and code updates, but all of them have good user support through forums or IRC channels. Qt has better support/userbase but is not completely free (but I can't provide you with details for that).

I have used Visual Studio MFC before and then when I wanted to have free and portable GUI I choosen GtkMM. I have to say that it was PITA to switch as GtkMM is not documented very well, its functionality is sometimes confusing, I had to recompile and modify few things (like widget with in-dialog OpenGL support) but I was able to finish my program successfuly. On the other hand, starting with MFC wasn't easy too.

But I'm not suggesting GtkMM over other ones. So I just can provide the list: Gtk, GtkMM (Gtk++), Qt, wxWidgets.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many C++ GUI frameworks: Qt, gtkmm, wxWidgets (all these are specified above).

Add [FLTK](http://www.fltk.org/) to that list.

Answer (score 0):

If it is only for Windows and you use Visual-Studio you may use **WinForms** or the more up to date **WPF**. There is a nice GUI designer in the Visual-Studio and it is free for any purposes.